# jQuery SerialScroll Tabs with Rotator

Tags: jquery, css

I have implemented the SerialScroll Tabs that is similar to Scrollable Tabs:

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/WvpcR/

I would like to modify this to enable the 1st Tab to always be selected, and then rotate through or paginate the other tabs.

Here is an example:

http://www.stceciliaschool.org/

I know that jQuery Tabs exists with Rotator, but I haven’t been able to locate the the code or how to download this functionality.

http://www.raymondselda.com/demo/tabbed-rotator/

Does anyone have any idea about how I could implement this existing SerialScroll with Rotator?

```
$(function() {     
    $('.navigations a').click(function() {
        $('.navigations a.white').removeClass('white').addClass('blue');
        $(this).addClass('white').removeClass('blue');    
        return false;
    }); 
}); 

jQuery.easing.easeOutQuart = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
};

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#mid-featureleft-client').serialScroll({
        target: '.sectionss',
        items: 'li',
        prev: 'img.prev',
        next: 'img.next',
        axis: 'xy',
        // The default is 'y' scroll on both ways
        navigation: '.navigations li a',
        duration: 275,
        force: true,
        onBefore: function(e, elem, $pane, $items, pos) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.blur) this.blur();
        },
        onAfter: function(elem) {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation that utilizes ContentSlider not the same as SerialScroll:

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/rQnQ3/

```
featuredcontentslider.init({
                id: "slider",  //id of main slider DIV
                contentsource: ["inline", ""],  //Valid values: ["inline", ""] or ["ajax", "path_to_file"]
                toc: "markup",  //Valid values: "#increment", "markup", ["label1", "label2", etc]
                nextprev: ["Previous", "Next"],  //labels for "prev" and "next" links. Set to "" to hide.
                revealtype: "mouseover", //Behavior of pagination links to reveal the slides: "click" or "mouseover"
                enablefade: [true, 0.1],  //[true/false, fadedegree]
                autorotate: [true, 3000],  //[true/false, pausetime]
                onChange: function(previndex, curindex){  //event handler fired whenever script changes slide
                    //previndex holds index of last slide viewed b4 current (1=1st slide, 2nd=2nd etc)
                    //curindex holds index of currently shown slide (1=1st slide, 2nd=2nd etc)
                }
            })
```